# Is there a way to add a pre created class to a vector?

Tags: c++

First off, I'm new to c++, currently learning it online.
I greatly appreciate any help...

I have a vector of classes set up for vehicles, however it should also contain derived classes for vehicles of different types (car, truck, van).

My class is set up to have functions to gather user input and assign that to different variables, I do not use the constructor for this. Is that wrong?

In my main this all works fine and dandy but when I go to add the class to the vector I run into issues, first off, My instructor informed us to use smart pointers for this, so I initialize my vector like so...

```
vector<unique_ptr<Vehicle>> vehicles;
```

This is how I'm adding classes to that vector...

```
// For base class...
vehicles.push_back(make_unique<Vehicle>());
// For derived class...
vehicles.emplace_back(make_unique<Car>());
```

This is where I am stuck, adding the class this way will cause it to be called and therefor the constructor called as well. What I would like to do is just add a class that I have already created and defined beforehand, for example..

```
// Functions to gather user input, validate and display...
   Vehicle vehicle;
   vehicle.getMake();
   vehicle.validateName(vehicle.make);
   vehicle.getModel();
   vehicle.validateName(vehicle.model);
   vehicle.displayVehicle();
vehicles.push_back(/* Somehow add 'vehicle' */);
```

Thanks for any help, I understand this might be the wrong way to do this, I was just struggling to find a solution and this is currently where I am at.

Comment: [`std::vector<T>::emplace_back(T&&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) will move `T` into the vector.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Posting your solution down below will make it an answer. (It's wrong, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My class is set up to have functions to gather user input and assign that to different variables, I do not use the constructor for this. Is that wrong?

A constructor shouldn't do lots of things, and never prompt for user input… but, at the same time, it should not be possible to have a "half-ready" object at any point. I suggest you gather all your user input *first*, then pass it into the constructor so your object is ready to go in one step.

*(I have not shown this in the following example.)*

---

> This is where I am stuck, adding the class this way will cause it to be called and therefor the constructor called as well. What I would like to do is just add a class that I have already created and defined beforehand, for example..

Your vector contains `unique_ptr<Vehicle>`s, so you'll want to start off with one:

```
std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> vehicle = std::make_unique<Vehicle>();
vehicle->getMake();
vehicle->validateName(vehicle->make);
vehicle->getModel();
vehicle->validateName(vehicle->model);
vehicle->displayVehicle();

vehicles.push_back(std::move(vehicle));
```

Notice that all the `vehicle.` are now `vehicle->`, because `vehicle` is no longer an actual `Vehicle` but instead a *pointer* to one.

`std::move` is needed because `unique_ptr`s are not copyable, only moveable.

---

Taking my advice from the start of the answer, this gets somewhat simpler:

```
std::string make = GetMake();
ValidateName(make);

std::string model = GetModel();
ValidateName(model);

vehicles.push_back(std::make_unique<Vehicle>(make, model));
vehicles.back()->displayVehicle();
```

I've moved the `displayVehicle` call to the end, because it shouldn't make a difference to your output, but allows us to do the "construct `Vehicle`" and "put it into `vehicles`" steps simultaneously.

This approach assumes that you have altered your constructor to take `make` and `model`, and set up free function `GetMake()`, `GetModel()` and `ValidateName()` to do those tasks.

Comment: Great insight, this solved my problem and will help me plan better in the future.